# How to dynamic enable/disable a ComboBox from ViewModel with a bool

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I want my `ComboBox` to be disabled when my collection is `null` or empty and to be enabled when I update the collection and fill it, in the same way as my "Connect" button.

I tried `IsEnabled="{Binding CanConnect }"`, but it starts disabled and is not enabled when I fill the collection with the button uppdate.

I typed this with MVVM:

**Model.cs**

```
internal class PuertosCollection : ObservableCollection<Puerto>
{

}
internal class Puerto
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public SerialPort Valor { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Nombre;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public bool CanConnect
{
   get
   {
      return CurrentPuerto?.Valor.IsOpen != null;
   }
}

private ICommand conectarCommand;
public ICommand ConectarCommand
{
   get
   {
      if (conectarCommand == null)
         conectarCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(Conectar), () => CanConnect);
      return conectarCommand;
   }
}
private void Conectar()
{
   currentPuerto.Valor.Open();
}

private Puerto currentPuerto;

public Puerto CurrentPuerto
{
   get { return currentPuerto; }
   set
   {
      currentPuerto = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPuerto");
   }
}

private PuertosCollection listaPuertos;
public PuertosCollection ListaPuertos
{
   get { return listaPuertos; }
   set
   {
      listaPuertos = value;
      if (value != null && value.Count > 0)
      {
         CurrentPuerto = value[0];
      }
      RaisePropertyChanged("ListaPuertos");
   }
}

private ICommand listarPuertosCommand;
public ICommand ListarPuertosCommand
{
   get
   {
      if (listarPuertosCommand == null)
         listarPuertosCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(ListarPuertos));
      return listarPuertosCommand;
   }
}

private void ListarPuertos()
{
   ListaPuertos = Generator.Puertos();
}
```

**View.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:ConfiguracionViewModel x:Key="ConfiguracionVM"/>
    <vm:DatoViewModel x:Key="DatoVM"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource ConfiguracionVM}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8">
        <Button Content="Conectar" Command="{Binding ConectarCommand}" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
        <Label Content="Puerto:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListaPuertos}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPuerto}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanConnect }" Width="Auto" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,8,0">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListarPuertosCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Command="{Binding ListarPuertosCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,8,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Recursos/Imagenes/actualizar_96px.png" Width="32" Height="32" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="/Recursos/Imagenes/ajustes_48px.png" Width="32" Height="32"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Label Content="Statusbar"/>
    </StatusBar>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource DatoVM}">
        
    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

I am learning MVVM with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0nnIa1W908&list=PLp5TyIbRCUZ6DKpnfv-G0quCd2gV-1Ne8)

Comment: not sure if neccessary, but did you put `DataContext=this` in the constructor of ViewModel?

Comment: @RomCoo It is not necessary, in the same View I am defining the DataContext with `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DemoConexionSerial.ViewModels"`, `<vm:ConfiguracionViewModel x:Key="ConfiguracionVM"/>` and `<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource ConfiguracionVM}">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple.

First create a Converter that receives an integer that corresponds to the amount of items you have in the collection, if the amount is greater than zero it will return a True, if not it will return a False.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class CountToBoolean : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value is int) ? ((int)value) > 0 : false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you create an instance of the Converter in the App.xaml or in the window you want to use it.

```
<cv:CountToBoolean                      x:Key="CountToBoolean"/>
```

And finally you apply it to the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListaPuertos}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPuerto}" IsEnabled="{Binding ListaPuertos.Count, Converter={StaticResource CountToBoolean}}" Width="Auto" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,8,0">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListarPuertosCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried `IsEnabled="{Binding CanConnect}"`, but it starts disabled and is not enabled when I fill the collection with the button uppdate.

At least from your provided code, you do not trigger the property changed event for the `CanConnect` property when it is changed.

### Disabling the combo box

You can add a style to the `ComboBox` that disables it if the `ListaPuertos` collection is `null` or empty.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
   <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ListaPuertos}" Value="{x:Null}">
         <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ListaPuertos.Count}" Value="0">
         <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```